# first five lines of stdout, bash

Tags: bash, stdout, trim, truncate

How can I chop off everything but the first five lines using a bash pipe? For example:

```
cat file.txt | truncate 5
```

would only print the first five lines. Ideas?

Comment: Rather than cat, why not `head -5 file.txt`

Comment: i'm not using cat in my real-world issue; i am just given STDOUT

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need the [`head`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_%28Unix%29) command.